# Azure AD OpenId Connect for users of SaaS Application

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I am migrating a "On-Premise WinForms App" to a "Multi-tenant SaaS App" written in ASP.NET CORE. The SaaS application will be used by multiple tenants and the tenants don't see each others data. In our legacy product, user profiles and credentials were stored in each customer's database and the CUSTOMER could add/remove users from the system, as they saw fit.

In a web environment, it looks like an Identity Provider is the suggested route, by separating the user profiles and credentials from the application data itself. However, much of our data is tied to a UserId, so its important to know which USER created a record.

Now, in Azure AD, the setup would put ALL users from ALL CUSTOMERS into 1 Azure AD. I don't particularly have an issue with that, but HOW do I know what CUSTOMER the USER account belongs to?

For example, customer ACME has 2 users: Bob and Bill. My other customer FOOBAR has 2 users: Jean and Jack. If Jean authenticates against Azure AD, I need to know a unique ID for FOOBAR, so I can filter data in the web application. When Azure AD sends back an IDToken from OpenId Connect, the TenantId in the claims is the TenantId of my company, NOT a tenant identifier for the CUSTOMER.

What is the recommended setup if we are going to deploy a multi-tenant SaaS application and use Azure AD for Authentication and still control which users can access the application? Azure Active Directory B2B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You group users using [security groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-groups-create-azure-portal) (one per customer) and [Configure group claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims) so that you get them in the tokens.